# Confused by coefficients that don't list their units

Tags: nuclear-physics, specific-reference

Let's suppose we calculate the energy released by the decay/fission of 1 kilogram of plutonium-239. Can we find the energy released in one kilogram of decay?

Wikipedia says there's $3.318*\times10^{-11}$ J/atom released. Now I multiply this by $(6.022\times10^{22}$ atom/mol$) \times x$? What is $x$? And is molecular weight in g/mol or kg/mol? Nothing seems to specify.

In doing research, the missing coefficient could be $1$ mol/$239.05216$ kg.

It's a shame the expertise to address this is not on this site, but this is what the dimensional analysis says otherwise, so I'll take this as an example for others of what is empirically the correct process until shown otherwise.

This site suggests the 239 in the denominator is in "grams" instead of "kilograms". Does anyone protest this?

Comment: Search term: “Q-value”

Comment: Wiki for some reason didn't mention it, I had to remember spontaneously. It's likely "molar mass". However, wiki then causes addition confusion: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molar_mass . Kilograms per mol? This means the higher the atomic number, the more I divide?

Comment: The Q-value for 238, not 239, is here http://nucleardata.nuclear.lu.se/toi/nuclide.asp?iZA=940238 . This is in kilo-electron-volts? It still doesn't seem to list what the Q value means. Is that the energy in one kilogram of decay?

Comment: Q-value is energy released per decay per atom, usually in electron-volts. Beware that "fission" can have many different Q-values, because there are many possible daughter fragments. Pu-239 has an alpha decay Q-value of about 5 MeV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your numbers (you have a typo in the exponent on Avogadro's constant):
$$E=\underbrace{3.318\times10^{-11}\,\frac{\text{J}}{\text{atom}}}_{\text{Decay energy per atom}}\cdot\underbrace{6.022\times10^{23}\,\frac{\text{atoms}}{\text{mol}}}_{\text{Avogadro's constant}}\cdot\left(\underbrace{239.1\,\frac{\text{g}}{\text{mol}}}_{\text{Pu239 molar mass}}\right)^{-1}\cdot\underbrace{1000\,\text{g}}_{\text{Total mass of Pu239}}$$
$$=\underbrace{8.36\times10^{13}\,\text{J}}_{\text{Total energy released}}$$
To answer some of your other questions:

- Molar mass is typically given in units of $\text{g}/\text{mol}$. It is the mass of $6.022\times10^{23}$ of an atom (or isotope), in grams. See this article on the [atomic mass unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalton_(unit)) for more details.
- The [electronvolt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronvolt) is a unit of energy, with $1\text{eV}=1\,\text{e}\cdot1\,\text{V}=1.602\times10^{-19}\,\text{J}$. It's standard in atomic physics where it provides a convenient scale so we don't have to juggle around exponents of joules everywhere. It's also physically meaningful as equivalent to the work done on a charge of magnitude $1\,\text{e}$ accelerated through a potential difference of $1\,\text{V}$.

Comment: Thank you, this looks close to what I got. I don't know why people on this site are harassing me for putting the work into researching, exactly what they complain about, but you did great work.